# I'm new to codeigniter: how do I convert this SQL into codeigniter model

Tags: sql, codeigniter

```
SELECT  stock_Code AS stockCode
                            , items.item_Code
                    , item_Name AS itemName
                    , item_units.name AS unitName
                    , item_Cost AS itemCost
                    , stock_Quantity AS stockQuantity
                    , supplier.supplier_Name as supplierName
            FROM items
            LEFT JOIN stocks  ON items.item_Code = stocks.item_Code
            LEFT JOIN supplier ON supplier.supplier_Code = items.supplier_Code
            LEFT JOIN item_units ON items.unit_id = item_units.unit_id
            WHERE stocks.created_at = (select max(stocks.created_at)
                                        FROM stocks
                                        WHERE stocks.item_Code = items.item_Code
                                        ) AND items.item_Code = '123'
```

Comment: Try the stored procedure; call in model

Answer (score 1):

I just try to help.

The query:

```
$this->db->select("stock_Code AS stockCode
                        , items.item_Code
                , item_Name AS itemName
                , item_units.name AS unitName
                , item_Cost AS itemCost
                , stock_Quantity AS stockQuantity
                , supplier.supplier_Name as supplierName");
$this->db->from("items");
$this->db->join("stocks", "items.item_Code = stocks.item_Code", "left");
$this->db->join("supplier","supplier.supplier_Code = items.supplier_Code", "left");
$this->db->join("item_units","items.unit_id = item_units.unit_id","left");
$this->db->where("stocks.created_at = (select max(stocks.created_at) 
");
```

if you need to get your single row data with array object:

```
$this->db->get()->row();
```

if you need to get your single row data with array:

```
$this->db->get()->row_array();
```

if you need to get your multiple row data array object:

```
$this->db->get()->result();
```

if you need to get your multiple row data array:

```
$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: Sir Thank You! It's working, Now it's the time to figure out how this query works. Thank You Master!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:--

```
$sql = $this->db->query("SELECT  stock_Code AS stockCode
                            , items.item_Code
                    , item_Name AS itemName
                    , item_units.name AS unitName
                    , item_Cost AS itemCost
                    , stock_Quantity AS stockQuantity
                    , supplier.supplier_Name as supplierName
            FROM items
            LEFT JOIN stocks  ON items.item_Code = stocks.item_Code
            LEFT JOIN supplier ON supplier.supplier_Code = items.supplier_Code
            LEFT JOIN item_units ON items.unit_id = item_units.unit_id
            WHERE stocks.created_at = (select max(stocks.created_at)
                                        FROM stocks
                                        WHERE stocks.item_Code = items.item_Code
                                        ) AND items.item_Code = '123'");
        $sql->result();
        $row = $sql->row_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use codeigniter model then 
1. create a Model in your model folder ( See codeigniter guide model)
2. write a function in model as

```
$sql = "Your query ";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

So you get result and return it. 
3.in you controller load the model class and call the function you made to get result.

However if you want to convert your query into active record that is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function aaa(){

  $this->db->select("SELECT stock_Code AS stockCode, 
                          items.item_Code, 
                          item_Name AS itemName, 
                          item_units.name AS unitName, 
                          item_Cost AS itemCost, 
                          stock_Quantity AS stockQuantity, 
                          supplier.supplier_Name as supplierName")
           ->from("items")
           ->join("stocks", "items.item_Code = stocks.item_Code")
           ->join("supplier","supplier.supplier_Code = items.supplier_Code")
           ->join("item_units","items.unit_id = item_units.unit_id")
           ->where("stocks.created_at = (select max(stocks.created_at) 
       ");
}
```